# Windows 10 Virtual Machine Licensing

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I have a laptop with a legal, OEM, version of Win 10 Pro. I'm trying to figure out if I have to purchase another Win 10 Pro license if I create a VM with Win 10 Pro on that machine. Will it recognize the license in the base OS and allow me to operate the VM version under that license?

This VM is for software testing purposes and would not be shared.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VM is not going to recognize the License of you're host computer. 
But you can use the unlicensed version of Windows 10 for testing.

The Goal of VMs is that they are completely different machines.